# How to add a bunch of defaults to python/django logging

Tags: python, django, logging

I would like to add in the following for every log entry:

```
user
request_method
status
```

The only way I've seen to be able to do this is a bit of a hackish way, which is to pass them as `args`, because that's picked up by the django formatter (I don't see any place where you can pass kwargs -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects). Here's an example:

```
log.info("hi", {"user": str(request.user)})
```

And the following formatter:

```
'format': '{"message": "%(message)s", "extra": "%(args)s"}',
```

When I parse the log I do something like this:

```
info = {
  'message': message
}
data = ast.literal_eval(extra)
for k,v in extra.items():
    info[k] = v
```

It seems pretty ghetto -- is there a better way to do this, for example, a way to get the kwargs in the formatter? When I try doing something like:

```
log.info("hi", extra = {"user": str(request.user)})
```

It either errors, or doesn't pass in the `args` (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by linking the request to the current thread of execution.  Here's an example of how to do this:

https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html

Then you can use `get_request()` in your logging handler to get the request, from which you can get the user.  (I'm not sure what you mean by "status")